# Android Camera: rotating output videos

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem with output video for MediaRecorder - it rotates videos at 180 degrees after front face camera recording, but playback rotation during recording is normal. You see, native camcorder for my device (Samsung Vibrant) has the same result for front face camera. My app supports Froyo (2.2) and higher, thats why I can't try setOrientationHint() to rotate output. Any solutions?
Thanks!